# Call function of the class, which can't call other functions within the class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I'm trying to adjust WP Woocommerce bookings plugin and add functionality for getting events from Google calendar API.

There's class

> Class WC_Bookings_Google_Calendar_Integration extends WC_Integration

, which provides token acquiring and authorization.

I added new function to the class

> public function get_googlecal_bookings( $bookable_product, $min_date =
>   0, $max_date = 0 )

that suppose to retrieve all bookings in between min and max dates for certain product.

From my functions.php I'm calling it with

> $existing_bookings =
>   WC_Bookings_Google_Calendar_Integration::get_googlecal_bookings($bookable_product,
>   $from, $to);

and this works with dummy data.

Although, when I try to use other class functions within `function get_googlecal_bookings`, like `$api_url      = $this->calendars_uri . $this->calendar_id . '/events/';` or `$access_token = $this->get_access_token();` I get nothing.

I know I call them incorrectly, just need to point me in the right directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling it as a static function `WC_Bookings_Google_Calendar_Integration::get_googlecal_bookings`, but you are referencing `$this`, which won´t work, since there´s no instance.

Comment: Thanks! Changed it to    ` $foo = new WC_Bookings_Google_Calendar_Integration;
    $existing_bookings = $foo->get_googlecal_bookings($bookable_product, $from, $to);`

Comment: yes, it does. I need to get into OOP more. I upvoted your answer, but don't have enough reputation to display that. Sorry :(